# Scroll bar visibility in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I got stuck where I need to display my `UITextView's` scroll bar permanently i.e. scroll bar should not disappear. I tried `[textview flashScrollIndicators];` for this but it doesn't make any difference. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
[textView flashScrollIndicators];
```

UITextView inherit UIScrollView. As UIScrollView has a method flashScrollIndicators to show the scroll bar that you can call to prompts the user that the view is scrollable. Note, It only flashes once for few seconds where user comes to a page that contains UIScrollView or its subclass. As you want to show the scroll bar permanently show you can use a timer to call this method.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f target:self selector:@selector(showAgain) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(void)showAgain
{
    [myTextView flashScrollIndicators];
}
```

`NB: UITextView only start showing the scroller when it's content size get overflow then it's height. And there after [textView flashScrollIndicators] this method will work.`

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to have them always display. Also they're scroll indicators and not scroll bars.
You could setup a timer to [flashScrollIndicators](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/flashScrollIndicators) at a given time suited to your app such as when the view appears or when some text input is detected using the `UITextView's` delegates.
I haven't tried using [this](https://github.com/BasheerSience/BRScrollBar) custom component but since the `UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, you could explore the possibility of tinkering with it and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `flashIndicators` in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLoad`

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.textView flashScrollIndicators];
}
```